# Store and update a Swift Dictionary in NSUserDefaults Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, storage, nsuserdefaults

I would like to store and update a Dictionary when a user enters a value. Everything seems to function until this code, and the application crashes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dict") != nil  {
        answersSaved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dict") as [String:String]
    }
}
```

The error message says "anyObject is not convertible to [String:String]. It offers to add ! after the as but then the app crashes.

dict is my Dictionary variable with Strings as values.

I also have code updating the NSUserDefaults but it appears to be functioning.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You would need `as!` instead of `as`. What does it say when it crashes?

Comment: It says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT next to the code

Comment: Console should show more detail than just that

Comment: Probably the object you're saving is not what you think it is. Show the code where you set the answersSaved NSUserDefault

Comment: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("answersSaved", forKey: "answersSaved")

Comment: No, I meant like the whole context

Comment: I declare answersSaved like this: var answersSaved = [String:String]( )

Answer (score 2):

Guess your Xcode's version is below 6.3.

Using `dictionaryForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`.`Dictionary` is not a class type in Swift,it is a value type.

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

userDefaults.setValue(["key":"value"], forKey: "answersSaved") // fill data

if let answersSaved = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("answersSaved") as? [String : String] {

    // [NSObject : AnyObject] can be converted to [String : String]

    if let value = answersSaved["key"] {

        println(value) // value
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I have, same error except with NSDictionary instead of anyObject

Comment: How about using dictionaryForKey?

Comment: I have tried above code in Xcode 6.3 and it works fine.

Comment: dictionaryForKey: is a method,not a type.

Comment: Shouldn't be a beta, unless you're talking about 6.4 beta 3. But why would you be running a beta if you're a beginner? Current release version is 6.3.1

Comment: Also, objectForKey should work fine for Swift dictionaries / NSUserDefaults.