# Storing a dictionary in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I read a lot on Stack Overflow regarding this question, namely, [Swift NSUserDefaults not saving Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752433/swift-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-dictionary), [Saving dictionary into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109813/saving-dictionary-into-nsuserdefaults), and [Store and update a Swift Dictionary in NSUserDefaults Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264345/store-and-update-a-swift-dictionary-in-nsuserdefaults-xcode). However, I cannot seem to find a solution that works.

Someone graciously provided snippet of code that worked for him or her but it's not working for me and I'm not exactly sure why. Here is what I tried:

```
var addressDict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()
    addressDict[3] = ["string1", "string2"] //some example values
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(addressDict) //archiving
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "address") //storing
    if let data2 = defaults.objectForKey("address") as? NSData { //reading
        let addressDict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2) //unarchiving
        print(addressDict2)
    }
```

I ran this snippet of code. And then I commented out `addressDict[3] = ["string1", "string2"]` and ran the application again. However, it seemed to be not saved onto memory since when this line of code executed `print(addressDict2)`, there was no data in the dictionary. Anybody have a solution to solve this? Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Try to sync the user defaults after setObject

Comment: Have you commented the saving line too? Or you expect that after you save an empty dictionary, you'll read the previous value?

Comment: @Rick van der Linde I tried to sync the user defaults by `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` after setObject, but it did not work. @Sega-Zero I apologize but I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: have you removed the line `defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "address") //storing` ?

Comment: Thank you so so so much @Sega-Zero. Yes it worked!!! But why?!

Comment: You instantiate a new variable an it's empty. then you write to defaults and then read it. What will be in defaults after you write an empty dictionary to it? :)

Comment: OOOOOOOOO. Okay I see. Thank you so much.